# cannot import scikit-learn for Flask application

Tags: python, flask, scikit-learn, mod-wsgi

Hi I have a small Flask application that needs to import modules from scikit-learn. However, it is ok when testing on local machine. But when it is on server, the site just keeps loading, cannot get any content loaded. The server is Apache. It's weird that I can import any other packages, .e.g numpy, just if I uncomment the line where I import scikit-learn, the website just hangs there. But if I comment the same line, the site can be loaded.

After some research I thought it might due to mod_wsgi issue. However, I cannot still not figure it out, as it mentioned on the official website.
in the section of "Python Simplified GIL State API"
https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/application-issues.html

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: What is your Apache/mod_wsgi configuration? Using ``WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}`` usually solves such problems with ``numpy`` and any libraries which uses it. Use check at http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#sub-interpreter-being-used to make sure you have it set up correctly. Also make sure you are using daemon mode.

Comment: Is there anyway you can do `import sklearn` from the same Python environment as your web server would, and see if there is an error/message?